# How can I get rid of an abandoned mutex?

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

**Summary:**

> **Is there a way to clear out a mutex if the process that created it is dead and gone?**

**Details:**

I use a mutex to make sure that only one instance of my app runs.

While testing out some new code (to do auto updating) I ran Environment.Exit(0).  While running in debug mode, my mutex was cleaned up fine.

But when I changed the build to be 'Release' then the mutex stays around after the exit call and is marked as abandoned:

[image: Abandoned Mutex]

I have double checked to make sure that there is not a process still running that this mutex is attached to.

Now every time I run my app, it thinks the mutex is still there and will not launch my app.  (It also crashes because it tries to send a message to the "currently running" instance of the app to show itself.)

I tried to free the mutex like this:

```
bool createdNew;
string applicationId = "18773:TestStudio";
var singleInstanceMutex = new Mutex(true, applicationId, out createdNew);

singleInstanceMutex.Close();  // Tried ReleaseMutex() too
```

but of course that just gets it andthen frees it.

I know I could just reboot, but I am hopping for a better fix in case this ever happens in production.

**Is there a way to clear out a mutex if the process that created it is dead and gone?**

Comment: According to your screenshot 3 things are still referencing it. Close whatever 3 things still have the handle.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain - The reference remains, but the process is long gone.  It died in a way that did not free the reference.  Hence my question on how to free up the mutex.

Comment: @Vccano then you have one of two situations. A corrupt OS install, or something has a reference that you don't realize is taking the reference. If it really was gone then the count would be 0, cleanup of handles from failed processes was fixed back in Windows 95 (or 98, I can't remember which). The likely situation is either the program is not really dead yet and something is still keeping it alive when you think it is dead or some other program (IIS, an antivirus, who knows) is picking up the handle and not letting it go.

Comment: Have you tried changing your program to do things the way my code does it, to see if that avoids the problem from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this actually answers your question, but here's the code I use for this purpose:

```
  // Mutex object used to determine if there are multiple instances of this program running. 
  //  Note that this is a reference to a .Net Mutex object, not the Windows mutex itself.
  private static Mutex _onlyOneInstanceMutex;



  /// <summary>
  /// Method to test that there is not another instance of the program already running on this 
  /// machine, or at least in this Terminal Services session or Windows Vista / Windows 7 
  /// concurrent sessions session. If there is, a message box-style localized error message is 
  /// displayed and the value false is returned. This implies that this method should not be 
  /// used in programs that are run as a Windows service.
  /// 
  /// This implementation uses a .Net Mutex object in public storage to prevent it from being 
  /// garbage-collected. The name of the associated Windows mutex is simply the program name as 
  /// provided by the caller. Neither the .Net Mutex object nor the Windows mutex are ever 
  /// explicitly released; they remain in existence, perhaps in an "abandoned" state, until the 
  /// process that created them terminates.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>false if another instance running, otherwise true</returns>
  [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2004:RemoveCallsToGCKeepAlive",
                   Justification = "Not sure if this is correct or not.")]
  public static bool TestOnlyOneInstance(string programName)
  {
     // Funny construct to prevent the Mutex from being garbage collected
     GC.KeepAlive(_onlyOneInstanceMutex);

     // Test if we are the first instance, and if so create the Windows mutex, making it 
     //  impossible for subsequent instances to successfully create their mutex
     bool firstInstance;
     _onlyOneInstanceMutex = new Mutex(false, programName, out firstInstance);
     if (firstInstance)
        return true;

     // Display a (possibly localized) error message, then return
     string errorMessage = MLocalizer.GetString("Error1", 
           "Another instance of this program is already running on this machine.") +
         "\n" + MLocalizer.GetString("Error2",
                                     "You cannot run two instances at the same time.") +
         "\n" + MLocalizer.GetString("Error3", "Please use the other instance.");
     MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, programName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
     return false;
  }
```

EDIT:

Only differences I can see in my code and yours is that I specify "initially owned" as false, and I have the funny thing about the garbage collection.

Oh, and I declare the Mutex static.