# Keep a cross-process named Mutex object as a local or field?

Tags: .net, mutex

I have two different processes (w3wp.exe hosting a WCF service, and my own custom Windows Service) that both perform a complicated database task that should have serialized access to prevent invalid state. (The task being performed is a three-step: 1. Get information from database, 2. Verify information. 3. If the information is okay, then INSERT - hence the need for exclusive, sequential operation.

The code is thus:

```
public static class Arbiter {

    public static void AddEntry(Database db, Entry entry) {

        Eligibility canAdd = db.GetAddEligibility( entry );
        if( canAdd ) {
            db.AddEntry( entry );
        }

    }
}
```

This code is not thread safe and is executed in multiple processes, so I should use `Mutex`, but how should it be maintained? I see two options:

#### 1: Static Mutex object:

```
public static class Arbiter {

    private static readonly Mutex mutex = new Mutex( false, @"Global\Foobarbaz" );

    public static void AddEntry(Database db, Entry entry) {

        if( !mutex.WaitOne( 3000 ) ) {
            throw new TimeoutException("Mutex wasn't released.");
        }
        try {

            Eligibility canAdd = db.GetAddEligibility( entry );
            if( canAdd ) {
                db.AddEntry( entry );
            }

        } finally {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2: Local Mutex object:

```
public static class Arbiter {

    public static void AddEntry(Database db, Entry entry) {

        using( Mutex mutex = new Mutex( true, @"Global\Foobarbaz" ) ) {

            if( !mutex.WaitOne( 3000 ) ) {
                throw new TimeoutException("Mutex wasn't released.");
            }
            try {
                Eligibility canAdd = db.GetAddEligibility( entry );
                if( canAdd ) {
                    db.AddEntry( entry );
                }
            } finally { 
                mutex.ReleaseMutex(); // this is necessary as Mutex.Dispose does not release the mutex.
            }
    }
}
```

Which approach is more appropriate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538524/how-can-i-get-rid-of-an-abandoned-mutex/25538839#25538839 See the answer I posted there. That is a completely different usage of Mutex, but the comments in my code might be of some use. I have vague memories of it being a bit tricky to avoid the .Net garbage collection discarding the .Net part of the Mutex.