# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Causing issues out of nowhere

Tags: c#

All of a sudden with no changes being done to the code whatsoever I am getting a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. The trace is as follows:

> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

The code for my entry point (what is throwing the exception) is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using DS4Control;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DS4Windows
{
    public class EntryPoint
    {
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
        private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
        private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        const uint WM_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0018;
        const int SW_PARENTOPENING = 3;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args) {

            bool createdNew = true;
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "DS4Windows", out createdNew))
            {
                if (createdNew)
                {
                    App.Main();
                }
                else
                {
                    IntPtr HWND = FindWindow(null, "DS4Windows DSDCS Build");
                    ShowWindow(HWND, 5);
                    SendMessage(HWND, WM_SHOWWINDOW, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(SW_PARENTOPENING));
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Global.SetupLogging();
        }
        private void HandleDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            string CrashString1 = e.Exception.Message + " (" + e.Exception.TargetSite + " in " + e.Exception.Source + ") [" + e.Exception.InnerException + "]" + Environment.NewLine + e.Exception.StackTrace;
            string CrashString2 = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Global.DebugLog);
            Trace.TraceError(CrashString1);

            try
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(Global.appdatapath, "Crash.log"));
                file.WriteLine(CrashString1 + CrashString2);
                file.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The exception is being thrown when calling App.Main() within my mutex check.

I know this code to work as it has for the longest time,

Comment: Read the InnerException.

Comment: Has your .Net Mutex object maybe been garbage collected? See the comments in this answer of mine from long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538524/how-can-i-get-rid-of-an-abandoned-mutex/25538839#25538839